# How do i interpret the function $X + Y$

Tags: probability

I have a question. What does $\mathbb E(X + Y)$ mean in this context.

Suppose random variables X,Y have joint probably density function $f(x,y) = \frac 4{81}\times x\times y$

Find $\mathbb E(X + Y)$.

The problem I am having is what is the function $X + Y$?

Do I distribute our other function across the variables $X$ and $Y$ then integrate (it is continuous) to find the Expected value?

Comment: What is the domain of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: 0<x<3, 0<y<3 for the variables

Comment: @user101562 That sounds like the _range_ of the random variables rather than the domain.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables defined on some sample space $\Omega$, then $X + Y$ is the random variable $Z$ defined on the same sample space by $Z(\omega) = X(\omega) + Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

A random variable is just a real-valued function defined on a (fixed) sample space, so when you have two of them you can add them pointwise to get a new real-valued function on the sample space.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\mathbb E(X+Y)=\mathbb E(X)+\mathbb E(Y)$.

Comment: isn't this for independent variables?

Comment: It is true in general.  But the OP might still want to know what $X+Y$ actually _is_.